# Select data from a table on the basis of different rules

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

There is table with Ent_Id, and I need the correct account Id for it.
There is certain rule to be followed in case there are multiple account_id for one Ent_id.

Rule:

- If Ent_Id has one Account_Id then pick that as Account_Id (irrespective of entity & close_date)
- If Ent_Id has more than 1 Account_Id then follow below rules:

  a) If Ent_Entity = Account_Entity and output is one Account_Id
  pick that

  b) If 1st rule give multiple Account_Id pick the Account_Id with
  max(Close_Date)

Table:

| Ent_Id | Ent_Entity | Account_Entity | Close_Date | Account_Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | a | 01/01/2023 | 101 |
| 1 | a | b | 10/01/2023 | 102 |
| 2 | c | c | 14/02/2023 | 203 |
| 2 | c | d | 01/03/2023 | 103 |
| 2 | c | c | 24/01/2023 | 201 |
| 3 | a | a | 13/01/2023 | 501 |
| 3 | a | a | 27/02/2023 | 601 |
| 4 | a | c | 07/02/2023 | 701 |

Required Output:

| Ent_Id | Account_Id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 |
| 2 | 203 |
| 3 | 601 |
| 4 | 701 |

I am trying CASE statement but not able to proceed on how to go to 2nd rule if 1st gives multiple output.

*P.S.- Close_Date format - 'DD/MM/YYYY'

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number() over (partition by order by)` and then choose maximum date.

```
SELECT 
Ent_Id, Account_Id
FROM 
(SELECT * ,
row_number() over (partition by Ent_Id,Ent_Entity order by Close_Date desc ) as rn -- this will assign unique row number for all rows 
from mytable where Ent_Entity=Account_Entity -- this will select only nt_Entity=Account_Entity
) rs
WHERE rs.rn=1 -- this will select the row with max date. 
union 
SELECT 
Ent_Id, Account_Id
FROM 
(SELECT * ,
row_number() over (partition by Ent_Id,Ent_Entity order by Close_Date desc ) as rn -- this will assign unique row number for all rows 
from mytable where Ent_Entity<>Account_Entity -- this will select only nt_Entity<>Account_Entity
) rs
WHERE rs.rn=1
and entity_id not in (
SELECT 
Ent_Id 
FROM 
(SELECT * ,
row_number() over (partition by Ent_Id,Ent_Entity order by Close_Date desc ) as rn -- this will assign unique row number for all rows 
from mytable where Ent_Entity=Account_Entity -- this will select only nt_Entity=Account_Entity
) rs where rs.rn=1 -- if you have multiple match this will pick single onr
)
```

EDIT : I modified the SQL -
this has two parts - union together -

1. This will pick data when Ent_Entity=Account_Entity
2. This will pick data when Ent_Entity<>Account_Entity

Comment: Koushik Roy, there is actually a first rule to be followed (had forgot that, included now) where there is only one account for one ent_id, after that only the other rules will follow. If I run on the basis of ent_entity=account_entity then for single cases it may not pick them. How to skip that, and pick all account_id when ent_id has 1 account_id.

Comment: Add `Ent_Entity` to partition by clause too.

Comment: This won't work right, as we are selecting ent_entity=account_entity in where clause. Its removing those cases where ent_id has 1 account_id and entity is not matching. But we need them as it has only one account_id

Comment: got it. let me change the answer